# Why my recyclerview isn't showing any item?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I just created my recyclerview to show a cardview when I just filling the required data on AddNewTimerFragment.java. But somehow it wont show the card that contains the data that I've fill in before. I've tried to changes something, but doesn't work.

Code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mobprog.ius.dwasu;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<MyListDataTimer> mintervalTimeList = new ArrayList();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private alarmListAdapter mAdapter;

    public boolean isFragmentAddNewAlarmDisplayed = false;

    static final String STATE_FRAGMENT = "state_of_fragment";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textUserName)).setText("Hello " + getSharedPreferences("Dwasu", 0).getString("user", ""));

        if (getSharedPreferences("Dwasu", 0) == null || !getSharedPreferences("Dwasu", 0).contains("user")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // Create recycler view.
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        // Create an adapter and supply the data to be displayed.
        mAdapter = new alarmListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mintervalTimeList);
        // Connect the adapter with the recycler view.
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // Give the recycler view a default layout manager.
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            isFragmentAddNewAlarmDisplayed = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_FRAGMENT);

        Button mnewReminderButton = findViewById(R.id.newReminder);
        mnewReminderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"Button Clicked");
                displayFragment();
            }
        });

        ImageButton mlogOutButton = findViewById(R.id.logOutButton);
        findViewById(R.id.logOutButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getSharedPreferences("Dwasu", 0).edit().clear().apply();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

//        // Get the Drawable custom_progressbar
//        Drawable draw = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.progress_bar, null);
//        // set the drawable as progress drawable
//        ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(draw);
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save the state of the fragment (true=open, false=closed).
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(STATE_FRAGMENT, isFragmentAddNewAlarmDisplayed);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void closeFragment(){
        // Get the FragmentManager.
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Check to see if the fragment is already showing.
        AddNewTimerFragment simpleFragment = (AddNewTimerFragment) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.FragmentContainer_AddNewAlarm);
        if (simpleFragment != null) {
            // Create and commit the transaction to remove the fragment.
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.remove(simpleFragment).commit();
        }
        // Set boolean flag to indicate fragment is closed.
        isFragmentAddNewAlarmDisplayed = false;
    }

    public void displayFragment(){
        AddNewTimerFragment simpleFragment = AddNewTimerFragment.newInstance();
        // Get the FragmentManager and start a transaction.
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();

        // Add the SimpleFragment.
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer_AddNewAlarm,
                simpleFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        // Set boolean flag to indicate fragment is open.
        isFragmentAddNewAlarmDisplayed = true;
    }

}
```

**AddNewTimerFragment.java**

```
package com.mobprog.ius.dwasu;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Calendar;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public class AddNewTimerFragment extends Fragment {

    Button startTime;
    Button endTime;
    Button meditConfirm_button;
    int startHour;
    int startMinute;
    int endHour;
    int endMinute;
    int position = 1;
    long totalSize = 0;
    String value;
    ProgressDialog progDailog;
    View rootview;

    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    private String sharedPrefFile =
            "com.mobprog.ius.dwasu";

    public AddNewTimerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static AddNewTimerFragment newInstance() {

        return new AddNewTimerFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_new_alarm,
                container, false);
        rootview = rootView;

        /*Shared Pref*/
        mPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefFile, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mPreferencesEditor = mPreferences.edit();

        ImageButton mbtnCloseFragment = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCloseFragment);
        mbtnCloseFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).closeFragment();
            }
        });

        //  initiate the edit text
        startTime = rootView.findViewById(R.id.startTimePick);
        startTime.setText(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        // perform click event listener on edit text
        startTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                startHour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                startMinute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog mStartTimePicker;
                mStartTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedStartHour, int selectedStartMinute) {
                        if (selectedStartMinute == 0) {
                            startTime.setText(selectedStartHour + ":00");
                        } else if (selectedStartMinute < 10) {
                            if (selectedStartHour < 10) {
                                startTime.setText("0" + selectedStartHour + ":0" + selectedStartMinute);
                            }
                        } else {
                            startTime.setText(selectedStartHour + ":" + selectedStartMinute);
                        }
                        startHour = selectedStartHour;
                    }
                }, startHour, startMinute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
                mStartTimePicker.show();
            }
        });

        endTime = rootView.findViewById(R.id.endTimePick);
        endTime.setText(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        // perform click event listener on edit text
        endTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                endHour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                endMinute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog mEndTimePicker;
                mEndTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedEndHour, int selectedEndMinute) {
                        if (selectedEndMinute == 0) {
                            endTime.setText(selectedEndHour + ":00");
                        } else if (selectedEndMinute < 10) {
                            if (selectedEndHour < 10) {
                                endTime.setText("0" + selectedEndHour + ":0" + selectedEndMinute);
                            }
                        } else {
                            endTime.setText(selectedEndHour + ":" + selectedEndMinute);
                        }
                        endHour = selectedEndHour;
                    }
                }, endHour, endMinute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
                mEndTimePicker.show();
            }
        });

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timeIntervalPick);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
                R.array.listtimer, R.layout.spinner_support);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                // your code here
                String[] valueListTimer = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.valueListTimer);
                value = valueListTimer[position];
                Log.e("Value of Spinner", value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }
        });

        meditConfirm_button = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editConfirm_button);
        meditConfirm_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String.valueOf(startHour);
                String.valueOf(endHour);
                String.valueOf(value);
                new MyListDataTimer(String.valueOf(startHour),String.valueOf(endHour),String.valueOf(value),String.valueOf(position));
                new UploadAlarmDataToServer().execute();
                position++;
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    private class UploadAlarmDataToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progDailog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            progDailog.setMessage("Menyimpan...");
            progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progDailog.setCancelable(false);
            progDailog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progDailog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String data = null;
            try {
                data = sendDataTimer();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                data = "Gagal";
            }
            return data;
        }

        public String sendDataTimer() throws Exception {
            URL url = new URL("https://ius.mobile.indoserver.web.id/alarmData.php");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });
            entity.addPart("startHour", new StringBody(startHour + ""));
            entity.addPart("endHour", new StringBody(endHour + ""));
            entity.addPart("intervalWaktu", new StringBody(value + ""));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            con.addRequestProperty("Content-length", totalSize + "");
            con.addRequestProperty(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());

            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            entity.writeTo(con.getOutputStream());
            os.close();
            con.connect();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            return response.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progDailog.dismiss();
            if (result != null) {
                Log.e("UPLOAD", result);
                if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data Alarm tersimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**alarmListAdapter.java**

```
package com.mobprog.ius.dwasu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class alarmListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<alarmListAdapter.alarmListHolder>{

    private final ArrayList<MyListDataTimer> mintervalTimeList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public alarmListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyListDataTimer> mintervalTimeList) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mintervalTimeList = mintervalTimeList;
    }

    @Override
    public alarmListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_item,
                parent, false);
        return new alarmListHolder(mItemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(alarmListAdapter.alarmListHolder holder, int position) {
        final MyListDataTimer myListData = mintervalTimeList.get(position);
        holder.mintervalTime.setText(myListData.getIntervalWaktu());
        holder.mtimeWork.setText(myListData.getStartHour() +":00 - " + myListData.getEndHour() +":00");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mintervalTimeList.size();
    }

    public class alarmListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mintervalTime;
        public TextView mtimeWork;
        final alarmListAdapter mAdapter;

        public alarmListHolder(View itemView, alarmListAdapter adapter) {
            super(itemView);
            mintervalTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.intervalTime);
            mtimeWork = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeWork);
            this.mAdapter = adapter;

        }
    }
}

**MyListDataTimer.java**
package com.mobprog.ius.dwasu;

public class MyListDataTimer {
    private String startHour;
    private String endHour;
    private String intervalWaktu;
    private String position;

    public MyListDataTimer(String startHour, String endHour, String intervalWaktu, String position) {
        this.startHour = startHour;
        this.endHour = endHour;
        this.intervalWaktu = intervalWaktu;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getStartHour() {
        return startHour;
    }

    public void setStartHour(String startHour) {
        this.startHour = startHour;
    }

    public String getEndHour() {
        return endHour;
    }

    public void setEndHour(String endHour) {
        this.endHour = endHour;
    }

    public String getIntervalWaktu() {
        return intervalWaktu;
    }

    public void setIntervalWaktu(String intervalWaktu) {
        this.intervalWaktu = intervalWaktu;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: " private ArrayList<MyListDataTimer> mintervalTimeList = new ArrayList();",this list is empty .that's why your recycler view is not showing anything.So Add "MyListDataTimer" object into list.

Comment: Yes Absolutely. please do that as mentioned  by @androidLearner.

Comment: yeah, I forgot bout it, now it's done